# How to exract the roots from "Roots"?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Given how the output looks like, as in a set of "==" assignments, is it possible to extract specific roots from the output of, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Roots.html ?

And then do a comparison?

Like if I want to extract the largest root among them?

Comment: Why not simply use `Solve[]` rather than `Roots[]`?  Max[x /. Solve[x^2 + 15 x + 13 == 0, x]]

Comment: Thanks! What is the benefit of using Solve over Roots?

Comment: The benefit of `Solve` is that it gives a `List` of possible solutions, so you can easily find the `Max`, `Min`, `Total`, `Length` (number of roots) or whatever.  Please give a specific example (code) so we can better help you.

Comment: `Roots` only works with polynomials.  Try `Solve[Sin[x]==0,x]` vs `Roots[Sin[x]==0,x]`.  In earlier versions of Mathematica `Solve` would only have returned `0` which is only one solution out of many and you would have had to use `Reduce[Sin[x]==0, x]` to get all of them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html) to convert the output to a list of rules.

From the documentation:

> `ToRules` takes logical combinations of equations, in the form generated by `Roots` and `Reduce`, and converts them to lists of rules, of the form produced by `Solve`.

Example:

```
roots = Roots[x^2 + 1 == 0, x]
(* x == I || x == -I *)

ToRules[roots]
(* Sequence[{x -> I}, {x -> -I}] *)

x /. {ToRules[roots]}
(* {I, -I} *)
```

Now you have a simple list of rules to work with.

---

Note that extracting part of the output using functions such as `Part`, `Level`, etc. is not reliable.  What if you have a single root?  You'd need to have a special case for that.  `ToRules` always works and it's simpler.

Comment: I agree.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to compute `Roots`, you can then extract the numerical roots this way:

```
myRoots = Roots[x^2 + 15 x + 13 == 0, x];

Max@Level[myRoots, 1, Heads -> False][[All, 2]]
```

or

```
Sort@Level[myRoots, 1, Heads -> False][[All, 2]]
```